# How Many Batman Canons Are There?

Tags: dc, batman, canon

When I see comic book questions, or questions on characters from comic books, they're invariably qualified with a "this canon" or a "that canon" only notice, which given certain characters is a fairly reasonable thing to do.  And of all the characters that exist, Batman by far seems to have the greatest number of intertwining canons.

Just how many different canons are there for Batman?  And to be clear, I'm counting all comic book canons, running and cancelled (but not 'planned but never released' canons), different movie canons, and TV canons.  I know there's at least two separate TV canons for Justice League and B:TAS (though not if those two are one in the same, or directly tied together with Batman Beyond).  And I know there's at least 3 different Batman Movie Canons (I think?) but I'm at a total loss on comic book canon.

Comment: That's interesting. I [asked something related](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67213/is-batman-mask-of-the-phantasm-the-same-universe-as-batman-the-animated-series) and I was told that B:TAS, Justice League, JL Unlimited and Batman Beyond where all within the same universe-canon.

Comment: @Deion Everything produced by Paul Dini is considered in the same universe.

Comment: [The Batcycle in the Christopher Nolan movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batcycle#The_Dark_Knight_and_The_Dark_Knight_Rises) incorporated several cannons. *\*BAT-DRUM STING\**

Comment: Correction: it's spelled Bat-canon.

Comment: I was just about to ask this after some confusion over my question [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/80814/41144). I'm glad I thought to [search](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/batman+canon) for it first :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Way, way, waayyy too many.

Starting with the easy ones:

**Television/Film**

- Nolanverse movies, which also includes at least one video game tie-in
- *Batman: Gotham Knight*, an anime-style animated film set in the Nolanverse, but not canon within it. My best classification would be that it's a parallel universe to the Nolanverse
- Burtonverse movies, otherwise known as everything from Tim Burton's Batman through Batman&Robin (My apologies for reminding everyone that Batman&Robin existed)<sup>1</sup>
- [The DC Animated Universe (DCAU)](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/DCAU): Batman: TAS, The New Batman Adventures, Batman Beyond, the Justice League shows, Superman, all the spin-off movies, and more.
- The 1960's show and its movie
- All the other Batman shows exist in separate continuities: The Batman, Beware the Batman, Batman: The Brave and the Bold, Gotham, etc.

**Video Games**

- The Arkhamverse (Arkham Asylum, Arkham City, etc.), which also include the animated film *Assault on Arkham*
- Except for tie-in games, the other games all exist in their own continuities

**Comics**
I'm not touching this one; there are about a hundred of them in total. The main ones are the DCnU (The universe of the New52 reboot) and Earth-1 (The old comic continuity). There's a full(?) list [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DC_Multiverse_worlds); essentially every time a writer had a cool idea, DC spawned another universe and another continuity. Additionally, every couple of decades DC would take a blowtorch to the tangled mess of continuity snarls and start over; you often hear about the Golden Age and Silver Age comics being separate continuities for this reason.

Such are the oddities when dealing with a 70-year-old franchise.

**EDIT:** As a final note, it's important to recognize that all of these continuities are interrelated. Obviously non-comic adaptations borrow heavily from the comics, but occasionally the comics borrow from the movies and TV shows as well. There are a few questions on this site about that phenomena ([This one about Bane](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46418/has-tom-hardys-portrayal-of-bane-influenced-any-other-batman-media) and [this one about *The Dark Knight*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20799/what-if-any-storylines-did-the-dark-knight-rises-borrow-from) spring to mind), and TVTropes has a whole subfolder devoted to Batman on their [Canon Immigrant](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CanonImmigrant) trope page, but some of the more well-known ones include:

- The characters of Harley Quinn and Renee Montoya were both created for Batman: TAS, but they ascended to comics continuity. Montoya has had a few major subplots over the years, including a weird thing with Two-Face, and now she's seems to be turning into a major supporting character in the *Gotham* TV show. Harley was an immediate fan favourite, was introduced to the comics in the "No-Man's Land" event, and now has her own title comic in the New52 (One of precious few female self-titles, alongside such veterans as Catwoman and Batgirl)
- Mr. Freeze's iconic, tragic backstory was also ascended from TAS. He was originally a pretty generically evil villain (See his portrayal in the 60's Batman show for an example), but the TAS writers turned him into an more complicated and sympathetic character

Similar to the above, many of the voice actors from TAS became so iconic in their roles that they can almost be considered ascended actors. Kevin Conroy, who has practically made a career out of voicing Batman, is the most obvious example, but Mark Hamill (Joker), Arlene Sorkin (Harley), and Tara Strong (Barbara Gordon/Batgirl) have also had long associations with the franchise.

---

<sup>1</sup> As you can see from the discussion in comments, you can make a strong case that *Batman* and *Batman Returns* exist in a different universe from *Batman Forever* and *Batman&Robin*. The radical shift in tone and imagery (Particularly the style of Gotham: compare the bleak, gothic architecture of *Batman* to the neon funhouse style of *Batman Forever*) present a strong case for the two-universe theory, but there are a handful of backreferences to the earlier movies that are hard to reconcile. Your mileage may vary<sup>2</sup>.

<sup>2</sup> An (obviously) unconfirmed fan theory I particularly like (Proposed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/FanTheories/comments/298dg3/does_anyone_have_a_fan_theory_that_makes_the/ciihpku)) is that they're in the same universe, but *Batman Forever* and *Batman&Robin* are in-universe Batman movies. There are admittedly flaws with this theory, but it's overall pretty convincing

Comment: Outside of becoing a mega-list question, this is probably the best answer I'll get.  Well done.

Comment: +1 for apologising for reminding us that Batman & Robin ever existed.

Comment: Also, I didn't know the TAS guys were behind Harley Quinn, Montoya and Freeze's backstory. That's pretty incredible! The show itself is fantastic by itself but It's cool to see it had such an effect on the DC universe.

Comment: @Daft I didn't know about Montoya until I was researching this answer. The show was such a runaway success, I can't imagine what else it inspired (Although the ongoing participation of many TAS voice actors in the franchise also springs to mind)

Comment: IIRC the 4 Burtonverse films at least all shared the same Alfred and Commissioner Gordon - Michael Gough and Pat Hingle.

Comment: @NikolaiDante Correct, and Chris O'Donnell as Robin was in both of the last two. But having the same actors doesn't it's the same continuity; look at Kevin Conroy and everything he's been Batman in. I was more interested in if the later two Burtonverse movies made dialogue references to the first two

Comment: @JasonBaker I seem to remember there being a throwaway line in Batman Forever about either Catwoman (something about needing to be wearing black leather and carrying a whip to get Batman's attention) or Vicky Vale (although that could have been from Batman Returns which is *definitley* in the same continuity as the '89 Batman)

Comment: @Monty129 YES! Thank you, I remember it now. In *Batman Forever*, Dr. Chase (The Girl One in that movie) makes the black leather comment

Comment: I'm pretty sure Batman Forever and Batman & Robin are NOT in the same continuity as the two Burton movies. There are far too many changes between them to account for otherwise.

Comment: @Omegacron It's a bit ambiguous. On one hand, there ARE pretty dramatic changes (Harvey Dent magically transforming from Lando Calrissian to Agent K springs to mind, to say nothing of the radical tonal shift of the films), but on the other hand there are direct references to events from the earlier films (Dr. Meridian's reference to Catwoman, which Monty129 reminded me of). You could make a compelling argument either way

Comment: I always thought the Catwoman reference was more to generic Batman lore than the specific events of Batman Returns, but who knows.

Comment: Gotham Knight isn't canon with the Nolan films.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell You're right; it appears to be in the same universe, but a different canon. I'll add a note

Comment: *Arkham City* also had a couple of [comic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Arkham_City_(comic_book)) [tie-ins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_Arkham_Unhinged), though their continuity seems ambiguous.