# What is considered canon in Batman?

Tags: dc, batman, canon

There are a lot of Batman movies, comics, games etc. that I am interested in delving into. But I have no idea what is canon.

For example, think of the origin of Bane. In the movies from the '80s, Bane's origin is that he is given a mutagenic substance and gains huge muscle mass. In the recent movies, he spends his formative years in the pit-prison. Surely he can't have 2 origin stories?

**How can I determine the canonicity of a Batman movie, comic or game? Or is the DC 'multiple universes' argument invoked to wash this all away?**

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/68668/31051?

Comment: @JasonBaker: I think your link justifies closing this question as a dupe.

Comment: @Accio_Answer Done. Also, nice username!